# extracting and concatenate parts of a string

Tags: python

I have a huge number of strings to process in the following manner.
For each string,the characters from position 3 through 15 need to be extracted ,except position 9.

So,for an input "F01MBBSGB50AGFX0000000000", the output will be "MBBSGB50AGFX".

The obvious way is `s[3:11] + s[12:15]`.
But given the sheer magnitude of data that needs to be processed,I need help on the recommended way to do this.

Comment: What do you need help with? String slicing is the way to do this, yes.

Comment: Are you sure Python is the right tool for this job?

Comment: What is the input format? How much data? How long can the process run for?

Comment: What is the "huge number" of strings? I don't see any reason why this would _not_ be the preferred way to do it. And Python should do just fine.

Comment: What is the expected output? what do you mean by `except position 9`? `"F01MBBSGB50AGFX0000000000"[3:15] ==  "MBBSGB50AGFX"` and `(s[3:11] + s[12:15]) != "MBBSGB50AGFX"` and `(s[3:9] + s[10:15]) != "MBBSGB50AGFX"`.

Comment: 1. When you say "position", do you mean 0-based or 1-based? 2. Your example is wrong, omitting s[9] should give "MBBSGB0AGFX" (leave out the '5'). 3. Getting positions 3-15 omitting 9 (assuming 0-based) would not use the slices you give, but instead would be `s[3:9]` and `s[10:15]`.

Comment: The main bottleneck is probably going to be I/O. The main scalability issue is in the overall processing model. If you read and write one line at a time, you should be fine; the upper bound for the memory requirements is the longest individual line, and there won't be a way to make reads and writes any faster (provided you're on a modern OS with proper buffering, i.e. you did not roll your own disk driver for your VIC-20).

Comment: Any particular reason to use Python for this? `cut -c3-8,9-15 input >output`

Answer (score 1):

When I have something like this, with fixed positions of strings to extract, I like using Python slices to predefine the fields of interest to be extracted. This may be a little overkill, but it keeps all the field position and length count information in a single easy-to-manage data structure, instead of sprinkling `[2:10]`, `[12:15]`, etc. about through the code.

```
#         1         2
#123456789012345678901234
samples = """\
F01MBBSGB50AGFX0000000000
F01MBCSGB60AGFX0000000000
F01MBDSGB70AGFX0000000000""".splitlines()

# define the different slices you want to get from each line;
# can be arbitrarily many, can extend beyond the length of the
# input lines, can include 'None' to imply 0 as a start or 
# end-of-string as the end
indexes = [(3,9),(10,15)]

# convert to Python slices using 'slice' builtin
slices = [slice(*idx) for idx in indexes]

# make a marker to show slices that will be pulled out
# (assumes slices don't overlap, and no Nones)
marker = ''
off = 0
for idx in sorted(indexes):
    marker += ' '*(idx[0]-off) + '^'*(idx[1]-idx[0])
    off = idx[1]

# extract and concat
for s in samples:
    print s
    print marker
    print ''.join(s[slc] for slc in slices)
    print
```

Prints:

```
F01MBBSGB50AGFX0000000000
   ^^^^^^ ^^^^^
MBBSGB0AGFX

F01MBCSGB60AGFX0000000000
   ^^^^^^ ^^^^^
MBCSGB0AGFX

F01MBDSGB70AGFX0000000000
   ^^^^^^ ^^^^^
MBDSGB0AGFX
```

If you prefer, you can also define the pieces to extract using `(start,length)` tuples, as in

```
fields = [(3,6), (10,5)]
```

Then convert these to slices with:

```
slices = [slice(start,start+length) for start,length in fields]
```

And all the rest of the code above remains the same.

Comment: It might an appropriate case for `operator.itemgetter(*slices)(s)`